# Neo4j - Dynamic delete cypher query

Tags: neo4j

I have following data structure of `neo4j` database:

```
           USER
         /    |
        /     |
     LIST     |
        \     |
         \    |
          CONTACT
```

means, `USER` have a relationship with `LIST` and `LIST` have relationship with `CONTACT`, but in some case, `USER` might have relationship with `CONTACT` (not all time). Now I want to delete `CONTACT`'s data. I have write the following query:

```
 MATCH (b:USER { id: {id} } )-[relationship01]->(pl:LIST {id: {listId} )
    OPTIONAL MATCH (pl)-[cnpt:USER_LIST]->(cn:CONTACTS {id: {contactId} } )
    DELETE cnpt, cn;
```

This query delete `CONTACT` with relationship with `LIST`. But in some case, I also have to delete relationship with `USER`. To solve this, I have write the following query:

```
   MATCH (b:USER { id: {id} } )-[relationship01]->(pl:LIST {id: {listId} )
    OPTIONAL MATCH (pl)-[cnpt:USER_LIST]->(cn:CONTACTS {id: {contactId} } )

    OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[bur]->(cnx:CONTACTS {id: {contactId} } )

    DELETE cnpt, cn, bur, cnx;
```

This query delete `CONTACT` with relationship with `LIST` and `USER`, but problem is, if there is no relationship between `CONTACT` and `USER`, then it throw error.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete a node until all its relationships are deleted, which is why there is a shorthand for deleting all of a node's relationships, then the node itself: `DETACH DELETE`

So all you have to do is this:

```
MATCH (:USER { id: {id} } )-->(pl:LIST {id: {listId} )
OPTIONAL MATCH (pl)-[:USER_LIST]->(cn:CONTACTS {id: {contactId} } )
DETACH DELETE cn;
```